# Snort ERROR: spp_session.c(2567) Could not initialize protocol session memory pool

Tags: router, openwrt, snort

I'm trying to configure Snort on an OpenWrt mini router by running

```
snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l /tmp/log/snort/ --daq-dir /usr/lib/daq/ -i br-lan
```

and I have this problem:

> ERROR: spp_session.c(2567) Could not initialize protocol session memory pool. Fatal Error, Quitting..

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi user9287503, We are facing similar issue. Got any solution for the same.

Comment: We are using 512MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too old, but probably one of your dependencies is missing.

```
apt-get install snort

apt-get install libdnet && apt-get install build-essential &&apt-get install bison flex && apt-get install libpcap-dev && apt-get install libpcre3-dev && apt-get install libnet1-dev && apt-get install zlib1g-dev && apt-get install libnetfilter-queue-dev # daq: nfq && apt-get install libmnl-dev && apt-get install libnfnetlink-dev && apt-get install libnetfilter_queue-dev
```

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enSll_9Bjag

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough memory on your machine. For me 1GB wasn't enough but 2GB is all right